# Mocking a function called inside a then block in a React Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test if a function(passed as props to the React component) is getting called with the expected arguments by creating a mock of it using Jest.

Below is the function that I am trying to test:

```js
handlerFunction() {

let response = [];
this.props.files.forEach((file) => {

  let responseObject= this.getResponse(file);
  responseObject.then((result) => {

    response.push({

      fileName: file.name,
      records: result,

    });

    this.props.sendResponseData(response);

  });

});

}

getResponse(file) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  axios.post(URL, file).then((response) => {

    resolve(response.data);

  }).catch((error) => {

    reject(console.error(error));

  });

});

}
```

handlerFunction() calls getResponse() which makes an AJAX call and returns the response data in a Promise. handlerFunction() takes the response data returned from getResponse() and pushes the response data and corresponding file's name into response[] and then calls this.props.sendResponseData() with it. I mocked getResponse() and made it return a dummy response data and testing if this.props.sendResponseData() is getting called with the dummyResponse that I created in test class.

Here is the code that I have written to test the above function in a React Component:

```js
it('handlerFunction', () => {
files= [dummyFile];
sendResponseData = jest.fn();

let wrapper = shallow(<RenderComponent
                       files={files}
                       sendResponseData={sendResponseData}
                       />);

let dummyAJAXResponse = {};
let dummyResponse = [{ fileName: 'file', records: dummyAJAXResponse }];

const getResponseMock= jest.fn(() => {

 return new Promise((resolve) => {

   resolve(dummyAJAXResponse);

 });

});
wrapper.instance().getResponse= getResponseMock ;
wrapper.update();
wrapper.instance().handlerFunction();
expect(sendResponseData).toBeCalledWith(dummyResponse);
})
```

When I try to run this test, it fails and says as following:

```js
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [[{"fileName": "file", "records": {}}]]
But it was not called.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try add retrun before axios.
Like that:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  return axios.post(URL, file).then((response) => {
```

or

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (

  axios.post(URL, file).then((response) => {
```